# SPSS did not accept numbers between 0.1 to .999

Tags: spss

I cant change output data when want to change between .1 to .999 and SPSS automaticlly change them to 0.000.
I dont know what is wrong with SPSS, i tried use Pearson analyze but output is 0.000 only.

[image: You can check this here]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you're after so please respecify your question, 0.0E0 = 0.

If you want the output to be in decimals only mark the area and right click and specify your decimals. Else you could change the width and decimals of VAR00001 and VAR00002 before you run pearsons.